# how do delete individual (dust) emitter particle that passes in front of the camera?

Tags: particles

I've made a video that is one long (5 minute) shot and created an emitter particle system to make dust floating around. it all looked good in tests and i sent it to a render farm and now im fixing any problem frames that came up. turns out, on 1 single frame one of the particles passed in front of the camera right at an important part. i cannot change the particle system and re-render the entire project as it took 31 days on a paid renderfarm to render. however i can easily re-render individual frames (which im doing for little fixes here and there that popped up post-render anyway)and just delete that one particle. anything i look up with the words 'particle sysytem' keep giving me solutions for hair paricles, so its getting pretty frustrating.
   So, how can i delete one particle from an emitter particle system when i cannot have any other particles change? I am using blender 2.79b still. (I'll move up to 2.8 on the next project... maybe)

Comment: I'm not sure if thats possible, but it sure would be nice.

Comment: You can delete a particle with an object by making it as collision-object and enable the "Kill Particles" option then place this object in the path of that particle.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**- @3DSinghVFX Genius! it worked. Here's what I did. I went four frames before the particle passed in front of the camera and placed a simple plane in the path of the particle. I turned off all ray visibility in the cycles settings under the object tab for the plane and added collision physics to it and enabled 'kill particles'. I then went to the particle system and freed the bake (from the 4 frames ahead to add a small buffer but not so far as to risk the other particles i want to keep from changing) and stepped one frame at a time up to the problem frame and.... PERFECT! particle gone.